# in_array confused about strict option

Tags: php

When I use strict option (which I was expected to be the best option since I'm comparing numbers to numbers) if never comes out true. But without strict it works fine! I'm just checking if array already contains post_id. If doesn't not add, if yes don't add duplicate.

```
if (!in_array($post->ID, $cookie_value)) {  
    array_unshift($cookie_value, $post->ID);
}

print_r($cookie_value);

Array ( [0] => 25 [1] => 1 )
```

So what is the deal here?

Comment: `in_array` does type comparison when the strict option is set. Your $post->ID value is not the same type as the types in your array. Try doing a var_dump on $post->ID to see what type PHP thinks it is?

Comment: I'm a bonehead. I'm quitting today while I'm ahead. ha.

Comment: can you add output of `var_dump($post->ID, $cookie_value);` ? Note that `var_dump()` will give you (us) the type while `print_r()` does not

Answer (score 0):

Why use strict in the first place, especially if without strict it works just fine?  If the string "2" is in the array, don't you want it to match the number 2? Unless your goal is to for example have both the string "2" and the number 2 in the array

There are very few times where I care about what type PHP thinks a variable is.  The way PHP implements [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php), I usually don't have to care.

I don't think you want to use strict.